# ASP.Net Core API routing without attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

I want to set up API routing inside `Startup.Configure` method using the same approach that is used for `MVC` actions by default, without `Route` attributes.
I try the following:

```
// API
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "api",
    template: "api/{controller}/{id?}");
// default
routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
    name: "spa-fallback",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

The controller looks like this

```
public class CategoriesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<Category[]> Get(int currentPageNo = 1, int pageSize = 20)
    {
        // return data here
    }
}
```

But it doesn't match this url: `/api/categories`. The next rule is applied instead. If I use attribute routing like this

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CategoriesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<Category[]> Get(int currentPageNo = 1, int pageSize = 20)
    {
        // return data here
    }
}
```

it works fine. But I want to avoid putting the same routing attribute on every API controller. What is the right way to configure routing in this case?

Comment: try inheriting your controller class from ApiController class instead of Controller class